# Undrstanding simple bytes output from scapy

Tags: python, networking, wireshark, scapy

I'm trying to print the payload of packets from IP `192.168.1.198` that have a payload:

```
from scapy.all import *

packets = rdpcap('capture1_bug.pcapng')

payloads = []
for packet in packets:
    if IP in packet:
        ip_src=packet[IP].src
        ip_dst=packet[IP].dst
        if ip_src=="192.168.1.198" and packet[TCP].payload:
            payload = packet[TCP].payload
            payloads.append(payload)
        
print(payloads[7])
```

and I get

```
b'$\x00\x00&\x80`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1bf\x00\x00\x1bfgM\x00*\x9d\xa8\x1e\x00\x89\xf9f\xe0  (\x00\x00\x03\x00\x08\x00\x00\x03\x00| '
```

I cannot understand this output. Why some bytes are `0x00` (2 digits) and some are `\x1bfgM` and why there are things like `(` and `|`? Why the first character is printed as `$` and not a hex number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x1bfgM` are actually 4 bytes: `\x1b`, `f`, `g` and `M`.  All characters in your bytes string that can be converted to ASCII characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, punctuation characters, ...) are printed as such and not using the `\x` prefix.  For instance:

```py
>>> b'\x24\x28\x7c'
b'$(|'
```